How do I send a object to a function?
I can't get the code in outPut to show on my lcd screen, what am I doing wrong or missing? Also I am not 100% sure that lcd is a object. This is for a Leonardo Arduino with Arduino ide but I have never been able to figure this out with Java and C++ also. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Keyboard.h> // The main library for sending keystrokes.


//LCD pin to Arduino
const int pin_RS = 8; 
const int pin_EN = 9; 
const int pin_d4 = 4; 
const int pin_d5 = 5; 
const int pin_d6 = 6; 
const int pin_d7 = 7; 

const int pin_BL = 10; 

int y = 0;

int z = 0;

LiquidCrystal lcd( pin_RS,  pin_EN,  pin_d4,  pin_d5,  pin_d6,  pin_d7);

void setup() {

   Keyboard.begin();  // Initialise the library.
  
  lcd.begin(16, 2);

  lcd.setCursor(0,0);

  lcd.print("Electropeak.com");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Press Key:");
}

void loop() {
  Keyboard.press('f12');              // Press and hold the 'f12' key.
    delay(100);                       // Wait for the computer to register the press.
    Keyboard.releaseAll();            // Release both of the above keys.
    delay(1000);

  int x;
  x = analogRead (0);
  lcd.setCursor(10,1);
  output();
}

void outPut(){
  lcd.print("Does not show");
}


Your outPut() function does nothing, because you never call it.  (You call output() instead, which is entirely unrelated.  I have no idea what that actually is, I'd expect an error on that line.).   Keyboard.press('f12') doesn't do what you want, because 'f12' isn't a valid C char value.  Keyboard.h defines constants for all of the special keys, I assume you want KEY_F12 (note that there are no quote marks).

In this case, since lcd is a global variable, it's available in all functions that can see its declaration (which is all of the functions shown). No need to send it to a function explicitly.
If you actually do want to pass an object to a function you can either pass by copy or pass by reference (you want this one for lcd). You'd write the function differently, like this:
// passing a LiquidCrystal object by reference
void my_function(LiquidCrystal& lcd) {
    // now lcd is available to use below
    lcd.print("It works!");
}

